# Passing a row as variable for PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a script that is using PasteSpecial to copy and paste rows as well PasteSpecial with xlMultiply to multiply some rows. The script copies columns A and B from the source file and pastes them into the destination file in columns A and B. In column C of the destination file, the values of B*0.5 are pasted. This script runs repeatedly such that new rows are pasted upon each run. As given below, the values of all rows of column D, instead of just the new rows, are multiplied upon each execution of the script. How can I pass the last pre-pasted row value of column D as a variable in the script? Appreciate the help.

```
objXLSWorkSheet.Range("Z99") = 0.5    
With objXLSWorkSheet
 'get the last row of column D
 DlRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.XlUp).Row
 'declare the next usable row in column D, desired pasting location
 DnRow = DlRow + 1
 LNG = .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.XlUp).Row
 'maybe the same as DlRow
 'RNGE = .Range(DnRow & LNG)
 'LINE ABOVE DOES NOT PASTE MULTIPLIED RESULT AS DESIRED
  RNGE = .Range("D2:D" & LNG) 'multiplies everything from D2, want "DnRow:D"
 .Range("Z99").Copy()
 RNGE.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOPerationMultiply)
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I discovered was to get the previous row count and set the range from the previous row count to the next row count and this seemed to work. Since the rows will always match, here's what seems to work.

```
'Row stuff for Column B
With objXLSWorkSheet
 lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.XlUp).Row
 nRow = lRow + 1
 oldlRow = lRow
 oldnRow = nRow
End With

'multiplication stuff
objXLSWorkSheet.Range("Z99") = 0.5    
With objXLSWorkSheet
 'get the last row of column D
 DlRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(Excel.XlDirection.XlUp).Row
 'declare the next usable row in column D, desired pasting location
 DnRow = DlRow + 1
  RNGE = .Range("D" & oldnRow, "D" & DlRow) 'multiplies everything from D2, want "DnRow:D"
 .Range("Z99").Copy()
 RNGE.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteAll, Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOPerationMultiply)
End With
```